# How to split strings in multiple columns into multiple rows

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a worksheet that has multiple columns filled with strings. I need to split the strings and have the targetted columns E, F, G repeat as many times as the columns with the longest string to its right.

From: [image: Data Input] To: [image: Intended Output]

Here's the link to the [sample worksheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qaLTduNXf-CalpEiZufwdHPPO2mzmYuri6GeACpF_n0/edit?usp=sharing)

The previous script that I used although could split all the strings in the worksheets, however if stopped at Column E. I wonder if I could modify this script so that it can cater to the remaining columns to the right.  Here's the script:

```js
const result = range =>
  range.flatMap(([a, ...v]) => {
    const { vv, len } = v.reduce((o, c) => {
      const t = c.split(",");
      o.vv.push(t);
      o.len = o.len < t.length ? t.length : o.len;
      return o;
    }, { vv: [], len: 0 });
    const temp = vv.map(e => e.concat(Array(len - e.length).fill("")));
    return temp[0].map((_, c) => [a, ...temp.map(r => r[c])]);
  });
```

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I hope this question is clearer. Do you think you could help with this?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/ See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for free resources and more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
const result = range =>
  range.flatMap(([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, ...v]) => {
    const { vv, len } = v.reduce((o, c) => {
      const t = typeof c != "string" ? c.toString().split(",") : c.split(",");
      o.vv.push(t);
      o.len = o.len < t.length ? t.length : o.len;
      return o;
    }, { vv: [], len: 0 });
    const temp = vv.map(e => e.concat(Array(len - e.length).fill("")));
    return temp[0].map((_, i) => [...(i == 0 ? [a, b, c, d] : Array(4).fill("")), e, f, g, ...temp.map(r => isNaN(r[i].trim()) ? r[i].trim() : r[i].trim() && Number(r[i]))]);
  });
```

- In this modification, the columns "A" to "D" are not processed. And, the columns "E" to "G" are copied for every row. And, the columns after "H" split the values.

#### Result:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- In this script, your sample Spreadsheet is used. So when your actual Spreadsheet is different from your sample one, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: ! This works perfectly. You are a genius!  Once again, so sorry for the inconvenience caused and thank you so much for the generosity of your time and effort.

Comment: @Phronimos Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.