# Split strings in multiple columns into multiple rows in Sheets - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to re-use a script that worked well in my sheet in the past, but I got an error when the script was triggered to run. The error message was "Custom function parameters too large".

```
const result = range =>
  range.flatMap(([a, b, ...v]) => {
    const { vv, len } = v.reduce((o, c) => {
      const t = typeof c != "string" ? c.toString().split(", ") : c.split(", ");
      o.vv.push(t);
      o.len = o.len < t.length ? t.length : o.len;
      return o;
    }, { vv: [], len: 0 });
    const temp = vv.map(e => e.concat(Array(len - e.length).fill("")));
    return temp[0].map((_, i) => [...(i == 0 ? [a,] : Array(1).fill("")), b, ...temp.map(r => isNaN(r[i].trim()) ? r[i].trim() : r[i].trim() && Number(r[i]))]);
  });

  // Credits: Tanaike (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70078195/how-to-split-strings-in-multiple-columns-into-multiple-rows/70081177?noredirect=1#comment123884616_70081177)
```

It seems like the error happens because I have too many data rows (the data rows are Google form responses and I have close to 20000 responses so far). Does anyone has any suggestion on what I could try to work around the issue? I'm actually unfamiliar with Google Apps Script and would appreciate it if anyone has any tips, thanks!

Comment: First, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. In order to remove your current issue of `It seems like the error happens because I have too many data rows (the data rows are Google form responses and I have close to 20000 responses so far).`, I proposed 2 sample scripts as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If those were not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, I thought that the values might be required to be put using the Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) and/or Sheets API instead of the custom function. So, how about the following sample script?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the values are put using the Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp). Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set the sheet names of source and destination sheets. And, run `sample1` with the script editor.

```js
function sample1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set the source sheet name.
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); // Please set the destination sheet name.
  const values = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const res = values.flatMap(([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, ...v]) => {
    const { vv, len } = v.reduce((o, c) => {
      const t = typeof c != "string" ? c.toString().split(",") : c.split(",");
      o.vv.push(t);
      o.len = o.len < t.length ? t.length : o.len;
      return o;
    }, { vv: [], len: 0 });
    const temp = vv.map(e => e.concat(Array(len - e.length).fill("")));
    return temp[0].map((_, i) => [...(i == 0 ? [a, b, c, d] : Array(4).fill("")), e, f, g, ...temp.map(r => isNaN(r[i].trim()) ? r[i].trim() : r[i].trim() && Number(r[i]))]);
  });
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the values are put using Sheets API. Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set the sheet names of source and destination sheets. And, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). run `sample1` with the script editor.

```js
function sample2() {
  const srcSheet = "Sheet1"; // Please set the source sheet name.
  const dstSheet = "Sheet2"; // Please set the destination sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ssId = ss.getId();
  const values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ssId, srcSheet).values;
  const res = values.flatMap(([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, ...v]) => {
    const { vv, len } = v.reduce((o, c) => {
      const t = typeof c != "string" ? c.toString().split(",") : c.split(",");
      o.vv.push(t);
      o.len = o.len < t.length ? t.length : o.len;
      return o;
    }, { vv: [], len: 0 });
    const temp = vv.map(e => e.concat(Array(len - e.length).fill("")));
    return temp[0].map((_, i) => [...(i == 0 ? [a, b, c, d] : Array(4).fill("")), e, f, g, ...temp.map(r => isNaN(r[i].trim()) ? r[i].trim() : r[i].trim() && Number(r[i]))]);
  });
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: res }, ssId, dstSheet, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
}
```

#### References:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: Thanks so much @Tanaike for the sample scripts! I really appreciate you for showing the two different ways in which we could get around the error due to a large number of data rows. I modified the scripts you shared slightly to split the items in the columns that I want to process. I noticed that both scripts are able to process the large number of data rows that I have without the error I mentioned in the question I posted. However, for some reasons (that I have not been able to figure out yet), both scripts start to do something different when they reach the 21169th row in the output sheet.

Comment: @Chai Thank you for replying. About `both scripts start to do something different when they reach the 21169th row in the output sheet.`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I have to deeply apologize for my poor skill. So, can you provide the simple sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating `both scripts start to do something different when they reach the 21169th row in the output sheet.`? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: To elaborate, starting from the 21169th row, the scripts start to separate the strings by using "." instead of "., ", such that some of the output cells contain a string that starts with ", " (i.e. a comma and a space). Up until 21168th row, all strings in the columns are separated by ",. ". I checked the raw data and seems like the problem did not come from the raw data.

Comment: @Chai Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. So, can you provide the simple sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating `both scripts start to do something different when they reach the 21169th row in the output sheet.`? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly! I was typing elaboration and wanted to attach the script I used as well. Let me create sample data for your replication :)

Comment: @Chai Thank you for replying. I would like to wait for your sample Spreadsheet and confirm your situation.

Comment: @Chai Unfortunately, although I'm not sure about your actual Spreadsheet, from `all strings in the columns are separated by ",. "`, if in this case, `,. ` is used as the delimiter, please modify `const t = typeof c != "string" ? c.toString().split(",") : c.split(",");` to `const t = typeof c != "string" ? c.toString().split(/,.|,/) : c.split(/,.|,/);` and test it again. If this was not the direct solution of your issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike! I'm sorry for the delay, I just created a sample data sheet and used the same scripts I used before this -- the scripts worked perfectly! The error I mentioned in my comment was due to multiple scripts running at the same time (as I created multiple draft scripts and did not delete them). So, problem solved! Thanks so much for helping me :D Have a great day :))

Comment: @Chai Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.