# Split strings in multiple columns into multiple rows with a Google Script/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, split

I have multiple columns filled with semicolon delimited strings.

I need to split the strings on these columns into rows.  The columns to be split in my example data are

B, C, D

In my actual data, these are columns.

X, Y, AA, AB with a last column of AZ

The column header are the actual column headers.

I can do this with one column but not with multiple columns.

Thank you for your assistance

A Google sheet with data

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZTVydSDpQegbj7qZElrJKeaIeWT5Wwna62NDPkJ_ZGs/edit?usp=sharing

Have

| ID | Authors | Authors Raw Affiliation | Corresponding Authors | Authors Affiliations | GRID IDs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA; BBB; CCC | Stuff1; Stuff2; Stuf3 | oStuff1; oStuff2; oStuf3 | AAA, (University of Oxford); BBB (University of Bonn); CCC (University of Zurich) | QQQ1 |
| 2 | RRR; GGG | Stuff4; Stuff5 | oStuff4;oStuff5 | RRR, (University of Oxford); GGG(University of Bonn) |  |
| 3 | MMM | Stuff6 | oStuff6 | MMM, (University of Cambridge) | QQQ3 |

Need

| ID | Authors | Authors Raw Affiliation | Corresponding Authors | Authors Affiliations | GRID IDs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | Stuff1 | oStuff1 | AAA, (University of Oxford) | QQQ1 |
| 1 | BBB | Stuff2 | oStuff2 | BBB (University of Bonn) | QQQ1 |
| 1 | CCC | Stuff3 | oStuff3 | CCC (University of Zurich) | QQQ1 |
| 2 | RRR | Stuff4 | oStuff4 | RRR, (University of Oxford) |  |
| 2 | GGG | Stuff5 | oStuff5 | GGG(University of Bonn) |  |
| 3 | MMM | Stuff6 | oStuff6 | MMM, (University of Cambridge) | QQQ3 |

[I did find this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71911085/split-strings-in-multiple-columns-into-multiple-rows-in-sheets-google-apps-scr) by @Tanaike, but it has no example data, and I do not understand it well enough to apply it to my data

```
function sample1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set the source sheet name.
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); // Please set the destination sheet name.
  const values = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const res = values.flatMap(([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, ...v]) => {
    const { vv, len } = v.reduce((o, c) => {
      const t = typeof c != "string" ? c.toString().split(",") : c.split(",");
      o.vv.push(t);
      o.len = o.len < t.length ? t.length : o.len;
      return o;
    }, { vv: [], len: 0 });
    const temp = vv.map(e => e.concat(Array(len - e.length).fill("")));
    return temp[0].map((_, i) => [...(i == 0 ? [a, b, c, d] : Array(4).fill("")), e, f, g, ...temp.map(r => isNaN(r[i].trim()) ? r[i].trim() : r[i].trim() && Number(r[i]))]);
  });
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even for me the original script proposed is too complicated for my simple brain.  Here is an example of how I would do it.  Less cryptic.

I fill each cell of each row with an array of values split from the semicolon delimited string.  Then loop through those arrays to see how many elements in each row and create a seperate row for each.

```
function splitColumns() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let values = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    let results = [];
    values.forEach( row => {
        let newRow = [];
        let length = 0;
        row.forEach( cell => {
            let newCell = cell.toString().split(";");
            newRow.push(newCell);
            if( newCell.length > length ) length = newCell.length;
          }
        );
        for( let i=0; i<length; i++ ) {
          let row = [];
          newRow.forEach( cell => {
              let j = cell.length > i ? i : cell.length-1;
              row.push(cell[j].trim());
            }
          );
          results.push(row);
        }
      }
    );
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+10,1,results.length,results[0].length).setValues(results);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in splitColumns: "+err)
  }
}
```

[image]

References

- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [String.split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Comment: TheWizEd, OMG thank you that saves me from having to reroute my data reshaping through Power Query. Thanks again!

Comment: For anyone wanting to use this, to restrict this to `just` the columns you want to run it on. Find-Replace `;` on those columns with a unique char. I used `¤` then in the above code, replace `let newCell = cell.toString().split(";");` with `let newCell = cell.toString().split("¤");` and it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

To do that with a spreadsheet formula, use `query()` and `flatten()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  lambda( 
    authors, rawAffiliations, correspondents, authorAffiliations, 
    query( 
      { 
        From!A1:F1; 
        flatten(iferror(authors/0, From!A2:A)), 
        flatten(authors), 
        flatten(rawAffiliations), 
        flatten(correspondents), 
        flatten(authorAffiliations), 
        flatten(iferror(authors/0, From!F2:F)) 
      }, 
      "where Col1 is not null and Col2 is not null", 1 
   ) 
  )( 
    trim(split(From!B2:B, ";")), 
    trim(split(From!C2:C, ";")), 
    trim(split(From!D2:D, ";")), 
    trim(split(From!E2:E, ";")) 
  )
)
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZTVydSDpQegbj7qZElrJKeaIeWT5Wwna62NDPkJ_ZGs/edit#gid=1546408026).